# We are getting an error with this while loop but cannot see why

Tags: python-3.x, replit

The error we are getting is that it is looping infinitely and does not appear to be picking a number to be the correct choice

```
import random
print ("Guess a random number between 1 and 10")
number = random.randint(1,10)
guessTaken = 0
print ("Guess!") 
guess = int( input())
while guessTaken < 6:
  guess != guess+1
  print ("Wrong!, guess again")
  if guess == input(): 
     print ("Correct")
print (  )
```

Comment: 1. What do you think `guess != guess+1` is doing?  2. Why are you asking the user for a second `input()` (and without converting it to `int`)?

Answer (score 1):

The loop's termination is based on the value of `guessTaken`; since that is never changed, once the loop is entered, it will never end.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many mistakes but I will try my best to fix them here:

First of all `guess != guess+1` serves no purpose you are checking if `guess` is not equal to `guess+1` (it isn't) which means that this line is always returning `True` and you aren't event doing anything with it.

I believe you meant to write:

```
guessTaken += 1
```

Which increments the number of guesses taken by 1

Next you will need to convert the second input to an `int` to compare it to guess so I recommend doing:

```
if guess == int(input()):
```

instead of

```
if guess == input():
```

Finally I suspect you want to exit the loop once the number has been guessed so I would add a `break` statement in the if condition as such:

```
if guess == int(input()): 
     print ("Correct")
     break
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes in your code. Not sure what you need, but you can try below:

```
import random
print ("Guess a random number between 1 and 10")
number = random.randint(1,10)
guessTaken = 0
wrong = True
print (number) 
guess = int( input())

while guessTaken < 6: #Maximum guesses are 6
    if guess != number:
        print ("Wrong!, guess again")
        guess = int( input())
    else: 
        print ("Correct")
        break #remember to put break when found correct number
    guessTaken += 1

if guessTaken == 6:
    print ("Maximum guessed")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to modify your code:

```
import random
print ("Guess a random number between 1 and 10")
number = random.randint(1,10)
guessTaken = 1

while guessTaken < 6:
    if guessTaken == 1:
        print('Guess!')
        guess = input()
    else:
        print('Guess Again')
        guess = input()

    if int(guess) == number:
        print('Correct')
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong')

    guessTaken = guessTaken + 1 #counter
```